# C# HttpWebRequest "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."

Tags: c#, .net, http, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a web crawler that need two requests. First request is a GET(create session) and another is a POST(submit form). When I try to submit a form I get the error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

I already tried to use TLS12, set keep alive to false, change timeout propety, but still don't work;
The stacktrace:

```
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
```

A print:

[image]

My request function:

```
public static string ObterHtmlPostTest(string url, string post, ref CookieContainer cookieContainer)
        {
            try
            {
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                string postData = post.ToString();
                byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                string html = string.Empty;
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                Stream dataStream;
                StreamReader reader;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                NonValidatedWebHeader header = new NonValidatedWebHeader();
                header.Add("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
                request.Headers = header;
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Accept = "*/*";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36";

                request.Referer = url;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

                using (dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                cookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, encoding);
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();

                return html;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm...Stream dataStream is allocated with a using block and then reused after it is disposed. Not sure if that might be causing problems?

Comment: To clarify: The dataStream in the using block causes it to dispose which might be closing the connection

Comment: @Nikki9696 I thought the same, so I wrote the OP code against `https://httpbin.org/post ` and it works. I get the response back.

Comment: @Nikki9696 
I tried to use out of blocks, still no success. I already used this function in other crawlers, and it works good, but in this specific website that I'm trying to get infos doesnt work the post, my get method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

The website I was trying trying to crawl use http 1.0 instead of 1.1. Have to add to code:

```
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```